# How can I make a diffuser for a 22 X 30 skylight shaft?

Tags: skylight

I need to make a diffuser to an existing 22 x 30 skylight shaft. A flush mount of some kind would be my first choice. My goal is to keep heated air from going into the shaft instead of the bathroom.

Comment: This is in inches, correct? How tall is the shaft?

Comment: As an experiment, you could use the standard window heat-shrink insulation, which is attached to the edges by removable double-faced tape. 3M is the big brand, but there are off-brand versions as well.

Comment: Just thinking about warm wet air in the bathroom and, if sealed cold air above causing condensation on the diffuser. Something to think about with this project.

Answer (score 1):

A standard recessed [ceiling diffuser](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VIJ8X6) (for a 48" light) would work if you installed a divider to support the middle section for two.